# How to debug https setup?

Tags: ssl, iis, https

I use my home network (ATT U-Verse) to serve my ASP .NET website on a Windows 8.1 Pro machine with IIS 8.5.  Because Chrome requires https for doing audio recording, I want to move to https. I followed the instruction video at https://www.netometer.com/blog/?p=1758 , and everything corresponds (IIS showing that I have a certificate in the bindings and an entry for port 443) until I test the actual https link in a browser (on the server itself, on an other machine on the home network, or externally via my phone with data), which gives me a "This page can’t be displayed" or equivalent message.  I added port 443 to the Norton firewall rule I already had.  The http access still works, however.  Netmon 3.4 shows no TLS or SSL traffic.  I also tried disabling the Norton firewall temporarily.  This leads me to believe that the problem is that either the ATT NVG510 router I have is blocking port 443, or that ATT itself is blocking it.  Looking at the router settings on the Packet Filter page, it seems none of the default "Drop" rules are enabled, and there is an "Enable Packet Filters" button. Do I specifically have to set up a "Pass" rule?

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do?  Can I actually do https on my home server? My web site is www.jtlanguage.com . Sorry if this is the wrong place to put this.  I'm a programmer trying to do some IT.

Thanks.

-John

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't doing port forwarding. For NVG510 users this is done by going to the router page in the browser to firewall->NAT/Gaming page and adding a hosted application referencing the HTTPS service and the web server machine name.